# How does the idle process and init process schedule?

Tags: linux-kernel

This code comes from the Linux kernel:

**kernel/init/main.c**

```c
static noinline void __init_refok rest_init(void)
{
    int pid;

    rcu_scheduler_starting();
    /*
     * We need to spawn init first so that it obtains pid 1, however
     * the init task will end up wanting to create kthreads, which, if
     * we schedule it before we create kthreadd, will OOPS.
     */
    kernel_thread(kernel_init, NULL, CLONE_FS | CLONE_SIGHAND);
    numa_default_policy();
    pid = kernel_thread(kthreadd, NULL, CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES);
    rcu_read_lock();
    kthreadd_task = find_task_by_pid_ns(pid, &init_pid_ns);
    rcu_read_unlock();
    complete(&kthreadd_done);

    /*
     * The boot idle thread must execute schedule()
     * at least once to get things moving:
     */
    init_idle_bootup_task(current);
    schedule_preempt_disabled();
    /* Call into cpu_idle with preempt disabled */
    cpu_startup_entry(CPUHP_ONLINE);
}
```

I know from the kernel start, there is a 0 process will init all the things when kernel boot, until this time, it runs the function: `rest_init`

Here: it will create the init process we call 1 process.

```c
kernel_thread(kernel_init, NULL, CLONE_FS | CLONE_SIGHAND);
```

after it runs the function, there should be two process now 0 and 1.

Questions:

1. 0 and 1 process are all at the same thread list in the same cpu(if there is 4 or 8 cpus platform) at this time? how does the two process dispatched?
2. if they are in a thread list in the same cpu, when 0 process call `schedule_preempt_disabled` function(), it means stop schedule.  Then 0 process enter `cpu_startup_entry()` in a idle time , and which process will set the `need_resched` flag to make the idle(0) process  to schedule?  I mean the process 1 won't run again?
3. or you can tell me detailed the 0 and 1 process how to schedule at this time.

Answer (score 2):

`process 0` calls `schedule_preempt_disabled` to do the things below:

```
1, sched_preempt_enable_no_resched();   //enable preempt

2, schedule();    //schedule to other process(1-init or 2-kthreadd_task)

3, preempt_disable();  //when all processes give up cpu, 
     //scheduler pick the 0-idle to run again; 
     //0-idle disable preemt and run into cpu_idle_loop;
```

Comment: i get what you say ,it seems this code must run on a non-single cpu platform?right?

Comment: Why would you say that? it can run on a signle cpu or SMP.